# Multiprocessing with Keras

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm stuck with the following error while I'm trying to parallelize training process over multiple cores. Any help, please?
or is there any other way to do it?

```py
from sklearn import datasets
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20,
                                    n_informative=2, n_redundant=10,
                                    random_state=42)

def train(x):
    import tensorflow as tf
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
    from keras import backend as K


    config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                            inter_op_parallelism_threads=1, 
                            allow_soft_placement=True)    
    session = tf.Session(config=config)
    K.set_session(session)


    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=64, input_dim=20))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
    K.clear_session()
    return x


import multiprocessing
ls = [1,2,3]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(train, ls)
pool.close()
pool.terminate()
```

> Using TensorFlow backend. Using TensorFlow backend. Using TensorFlow
>   backend. Epoch 1/5 Exception in thread Thread-9: Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801,
>   in __bootstrap_inner self.run() File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
>   self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 389, in
>   _handle_results task = get() TypeError: ('init() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)', , ())

Comment: this code works fine for me. I use: multiprocessing.__version__
'0.70a1', sklearn.__version__ '0.18.2', numpy.__version__'1.13.1', scipy.__version__'0.19.1', keras.__version__
'2.0.9', tensorflow.__version__'1.4.0'. Can you check your versions ?

Comment: Try adding a number of processes to your `Pool` creation.

Comment: sera Do you mind if I see your output?

Comment: @james here https://ufile.io/mkf2y  choose slow download after waiting 4 secs